# Field ... in ... a bean of type 'service' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to use an object which is in an external library, but when I use the @Autowired property, it is not found by the application.

The main application has the following annotations:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.XXXX.prj.business.modules"})
@EntityScan("com.XXXX.prj")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.XXXX.prj.business.modules.repositories"})
```

In the com.XXXX.prj.business.modules I have a class that calls the object of the dependency, called MailService, in this way:

```
@Component
public class MailNotificatorImpl implements Notificator {

    @Autowired
    private MailService mailService;
```

Here is the problem, this mailService object is not found as a bean type. The MailService is in an external library, called YYYY-commons. The class of the library has the interface and its implementation, and the implementation has this annotation:

```
@Service("mailService")
public class MailServiceImpl extends GenericService implements MailService, Serializable {
```

I don't know what I'm doing bad because in other application I use in the same way and it's working.

Can you give me some help in this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try adding the external lib's package to the array of `basePackages`.

Comment: how are you running this application? is it a Maven/Gradle application? is it running from command line? (java ...)
have you specified a classpath? is the external library in your classpath?

Comment: It is Maven and my external library is called from pom, like a dependency because I have in my maven repository. It's working correctly but the problem is in the @Autowired operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component scan, you are only scanning  the defined package, and any sub-package from there. This meand that the third party lib is not caught in the component scan, hence the bean is not registered.

The options you have is to:

1. use the `@ComponentScan` annotation on your main application class and add both your own base package, and the package of the third party lib.

```java
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.base.package", "third.party.package"})
public class MySpringBootApplication{}
```

2. register the bean yourself by adding something like the below to e.g. your main application class:

```java
@Bean
public MailService mailServiceBean() {
  return new MailServiceImple();
}
```

Comment: My application is working using the first option. Thanks!